# Convert unsigned int to Time in System-verilog

Tags: system-verilog

I have in large part of my System-Verilog code used parameters to define different waiting times such as:

```
int unsigned    HALF_SPI_CLOCK = ((SYSTEM_CLK_PERIOD/2)*DIVISION_FACTOR); //DEFINES THE TIME
```

Now since I define a timescale in my files I can directly use these params to introduce waiting cycles:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
initial begin
    #HALF_SPI_CLOCK; 
end
```

Now I want to have time-specified delays everywhere. Means that the simulation will still respect all the timings even if I change the timescale. I would like to keep the parameters but wherever I have a wait statement, I need to specify the time. Something like

```
#(HALF_SPI_CLOCK) ns;
```

But this is not accepted by Modelsim. Is there a way to cast a parameter or an Unsigned int to a variable of type time in System-Verilog? Is there a way to specify the time unit? I have looked around but could not find any workaround. 
The reason why I want to have control over the time and make it independent from the `timescale is because I intend to change the`timescale later to try to make my simulation faster. 
Other recommendations or thoughts are very welcome*

Comment: I would consider using `timeunit 1ns` inside each module, then no need to worry about the last call to  `timescale.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to pass time as a parameter in SystemVerilog, like:

```
module my_module #(time MY_TIME = 100ns);

  initial begin
    #MY_TIME;
    $display("[%t] End waiting", $time);
  end

endmodule
```

Or use multiplication to get the right time units, like:

```
module my_module2 #(longint MY_TIME = 100);

  initial begin
    # (MY_TIME * 1us);
    $display("[%t] End waiting 2", $time);
  end

endmodule
```

See runnable example on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/m2

Comment: Yes that is right. However I sometimes I need to derive a waiting time from different parameters I have in my module. The calculation is done on run-time of some important waiting periods and therefore I need to cast - on the fly - to a TIME variable...

Comment: @MehdiTabs Using multiplication is probably the best solution here.

Answer (score 2):

This will simulate and do what you want.  While not the most elegant, it works.

```
task wait_ns(int num);
  repeat (num) #1ns;
endtask 

...

wait_ns(HALF_SPI_CLOCK);
```

This *could* have a negative impact simulation speed depending on how the timescale, clock events, and the unit of delay relate to each other.

Comment: Thanks @dwikle Actually the best option I found so far is to multiply by 1ns. I first create `unsigned int waiting_abs` then I calculate it using different timing parameters. I also create `time waiting_ns`. Then it is easy to cast => `waiting_ns = waiting_abs * 1ns;`